# How to manage token authentication in android app

Tags: android, authentication, android-volley, jwt

I am using JWT to manage server authentication for my application. I manage it in the server. In my angular app, I am using `angular-jwt` to manage jwt. If it expired how to call refresh token API. I am using volley for API call. When the token is expired the server responds with 401 error code. That time needs to call a refresh token api. After refresh call, i need to call the previous API call again without any user input.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (method, request_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
                            if (response.getInt("status") == 1) {
                                callback.onSuccessResponse(response.get("data"));
                            } else {
                                callback.onSuccessResponse(new JSONArray());
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                        if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.statusCode == 401) {

                        }

                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String token = AppPreferencesHelper.getAccessToken(context);
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                return headers;
            }
        };

        Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call api to validate token, if its expired than you can generate new.

Or if you have login feature than you can check for JWT in login and generate new if old expired.

I have use a very basic way in my app, I am creating a JWT using a unique email address per user and stores it into database in server and it never expires. Whenever a user logout, I remove the JWT and when login again I generate new token.